# Can't mount system android : read file only

Tags: android, console, system, root

When I try to mount /system to read and write it says "read-file only"

```
mount -o remount rw /system/
mount: read-only file system
```

My tablet is only pre rooted and i can't finalize root if i can't write system ...  (i have "su" permissions # )

Comment: `-o remount,rw`, but what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: This would typically be more appropriate for android.stackexchange, or perhaps superuser (though the android tools can have non-standard options)

Comment: Excuse me i'm new here if some one could tell how to change this ...